# Check if the last letter of a name is an s or x or neither nor

Tags: conditionals

In German we have a (often disregarded) rule for using apostrophes.

In English it is like so:

```
"This is Mike's chair."
```

In German it depends on the names ending.
It's like this:

`"Das ist Mikes Stuhl."` (appended letter s)

BUT: if the name ends to s or letters that sound like an s (like x) instead
of a s an apostrophe is attached:

```
"Das ist Alex' Stuhl" or
"Das ist Andreas' Messer."
```

If I want to write a story for a class I would like to use name of students
but names change over the years and i will keep the story only changing the names in the preamble. So i have to create something like:

```
\newcommand\studentsname{Mike}
```

So i can use in the story

```
"So this is \studentsname"
```

But i would also need a command like \studentsnamesuffix and i don't have
an idea how to check if the last letter of the \studentsname is a s or not.

```
\newcommand\studentsnamesuffix{
 %if \studentsname last letter is s or x
 '
 %else
 s 
  }
```

Does anybody have an idea, how to solve this?

minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\studentsname{Mike}
\newcommand\studentsnamesuffix{
 if % check if \studentsname last letter is s
 '
 else
 s 
  }

\begin{document}

"\studentsname du bist spät dran!" ... long long story ...

"Nimm die Finger weg, das ist \studentsname\studentsnamesuffix."

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier if you say what suffix to add when you define the macro for the name; if the name ends with a letter requiring an apostrophe, use `\newname*` for defining the macro, otherwise use `\newname`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@apostrophe
\newcommand{\gen}{\if@apostrophe'\else s\fi}
\newcommand{\newname}{\@ifstar{\@snewname}{\@newname}}
\newcommand{\@snewname}[2]{\newcommand#1{\@apostrophetrue#2}}
\newcommand{\@newname}[2]{\newcommand#1{\@apostrophefalse#2}}
\makeatother

\newname{\studentA}{Mike}
\newname*{\studentB}{Alex}


\begin{document}

"`\studentA{} du bist spät dran!"' ... long long story ...

"`Nimm die Finger weg, das ist \studentA\gen."'

"`\studentB{} du bist spät dran!"' ... long long story ...

"`Nimm die Finger weg, das ist \studentB\gen."'

\studentA\gen

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution.